# Problem after the upgrade from 7.6.32 to 8.7.29

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have just performed the upgrade of typo3 from 7.6.32 to 8.7.29 following the official documentation. Actually the upgrade went just fine and I was able to perform all required steps using the install tool (in particular Upgrade Wizard and Important actions). 
After the upgrade the FE seems to work just fine anyway there are some problem in the BE.

Each time I tried to log in to the BE I got the following typo3 exception:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception\InvalidVariableException' not found

Error thrown in file
/var/www/mysite/typo3_src-8.7.29/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/TranslateViewHelper.php in line 133.
```

The line 133 of this file is part of the function "renderStatic" and here is the code:

```
110.    public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
111.    {
112.        $key = $arguments['key'];
113.        $id = $arguments['id'];
114.        $default = $arguments['default'];
115.        $htmlEscape = $arguments['htmlEscape'];
116.        $extensionName = $arguments['extensionName'];
117.        $arguments = $arguments['arguments'];
118.
119.        if ($htmlEscape !== null) {
120.            GeneralUtility::logDeprecatedViewHelperAttribute(
121.                'htmlEscape',
122.                $renderingContext,
123.                'Please wrap the view helper in <f:format.raw> if you want to disable HTML escaping, which is enabled by default now.'
124.            );
125.        }
126.
127.        // Wrapper including a compatibility layer for TYPO3 Flow Translation
128.        if ($id === null) {
129.            $id = $key;
130.        }
131.
132.   if ((string)$id === '') {
133.            throw new InvalidVariableException('An argument "key" or "id" has to be provided', 1351584844);
134.        }
```

Despite this error the main menu on the left of the BE seems to work fine except the fact that if I go "DB check" --> "Relations" I got this other exception:

```
#1476107295: PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/mysite/typo3_src-8.7.29/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Integrity/DatabaseIntegrityCheck.php line 352 (More information)
```

And here is the relevant part of the code for this file.

```
347   public function getGroupFields($mode)
348    {
349        $result = [];
350        foreach ($GLOBALS['TCA'] as $table => $tableConf) {
351            $cols = $GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['columns'];
352            foreach ($cols as $field => $config) {
353                if ($config['config']['type'] === 'group') {
354                    if ((!$mode || $mode === 'file') && $config['config']['internal_type'] === 'file' || (!$mode || $mode ==='db') && $config['config']['internal_type'] === 'db') {
355                        $result[$table][] = $field;
356                    }
357                }
358                if ((!$mode || $mode === 'db') && $config['config']['type'] === 'select' && $config['config']['foreign_table']) {
359                    $result[$table][] = $field;
360                }
361            }
362            if ($result[$table]) {
363                $result[$table] = implode(',', $result[$table]);
364            }
365        }
366        return $result;
367    }



As far as I can see all the rest works fine. 


My system details:

- Linux (kernel 4.4.190)
- Apache 2.4.39
- PHP 7.2.24
- Typo3 8.7.29

Thanks in advance for your help!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate issues here:

The first one is that something is using the

The second one is that your TCA is obviously corrupt. There is a table, which has no column definitions.

Both things may be caused by some extension, so try disabling all extensions as far as possible and re-enable them one by one.

Comment: Thanks!  Actually both problems were related to some of the loaded extensions! For some strange reason the check on broken extensions of the typo3 install tool did detect any problem... Anyway when I disabled and than enabled again some of the loaded extensions an error/warning message shown up.

Comment: @gdamad would you mind marking my answer as correct then please? That's how stackoverflow works. Thanks.